# how add a third condition to IF statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i have a condition [here](https://github.com/SimonItaly/iconping_gnome/blob/master/extension.js) line 175 and im trying to add a 3rd condition if ping is more than 200 then display "iconko"

i have tried this and it didn't work

```
if (result != null) {
    var ping = parseFloat(result[1]);
    if (ping > 100.0) {
        this.createPingIcon('iconslow');
    }
    else if (ping > 200.0) {
        this.createPingIcon('iconko');
    }
    else {
        this.createPingIcon('iconok');
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like you want javascript, not bash, I'm going to remove that tag to help get more targeted help.  If you really do think you need bash help, you can add the tag back again.

Comment: Hello and welcome!
Please take a moment to go through your IF logic. What will be checked first? What will be checked second?

Answer (score 0):

Your first if statement is catching all pings greater than `100`, and therefore is also catching cases where ping is greater than `200`.

You can fix this by ensuring the first if statement only catches numbers greater than `100`, and less or equal to `200`.

```
if (result != null) {
    var ping = parseFloat(result[1]);
    if (ping > 100.0 && ping <= 200) {
        this.createPingIcon('iconslow');
    } else if (ping > 200.0) {
        this.createPingIcon('iconko');
    } else {
        this.createPingIcon('iconok');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what the first condition will evaluate to when `ping` is 200:

```
if(ping > 100.0) // 200 is greater than 100, so this is true
{
    this.createPingIcon('iconslow');
}
else if(ping > 200.0) // And now this won't be checked since the previous check was true
{
    this.createPingIcon('iconko');
}
```

Just reverse the conditions so the 200 check happens first:

```
if(ping > 200.0)
{
    this.createPingIcon('iconko');

}
else if(ping > 100.0)
{
    this.createPingIcon('iconslow');
}
```